# Apply Liquibase script on startup of Spring Boot based docker container fails using docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile, liquibase, application.properties

I am trying to deploy an application on a ubuntu (22.04) vm using docker compose. Part of the application exists of a Spring Boot image which serves backend purposes. It is linked to a MySQL database container. On startup of the Spring Boot application a Liquibase changelog is applied, which contains the database schema and some data.

When running docker compose on my local machine (macOS), everything is working fine. But running docker compose on the vm, results in a tree of error messages related to Liquibase not being able to apply the changelog file (as far as I understand). I only added the exceptions, in order to spare you the whole stack trace. See below.

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - 
cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure
```

Due to the mentioning that their is a 'Communications link failure' my first thought was that this should be an issue with a wrong port mapping or some IP related issue between the Spring Boot container not being able to connect to the MySQL container. In the latter case I would imagine another exception though, mentioning something about the Connection not being able to establish. I added the following line to my /etc/hosts file:

```
172.17.0.1 host.docker.internal
```

as it was mentioned in other posts as possible solution for the 'Communications link failure' error. However, the error persists and my best guess is that this has something to do with the Spring Boot image lacking the actual Liquibase changelog information. I am trying to add this changelog information in the Dockerfile, which looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /usr/app
ARG JAR_FILE=/build/libs/*.jar
ARG LIQUIBASE=/build/resources/main/db/
COPY $JAR_FILE .
COPY $LIQUIBASE .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "player-pass-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

When running this Dockerfile a changelog directory is created in the working directory of the container, which contains the liquibase changelog file. I adjusted the liquibase classpath url in the application.properties of the Spring Boot application to point to this location. The application.properties file looks like this:

```
spring.application.name=player-pass-backend
server.port=3001

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/play_pass_db
spring.datasource.username=someuser
spring.datasource.password=somesecretpassword
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Building the application is done by a docker compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  player-pass-database:
    container_name: player-pass-db
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    networks:
      - local_net
    env_file:
      - .env-database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - player-pass-db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD","mysqladmin","ping","-h","localhost","-uroot","-prootsecretpassword"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20

  player-pass-backend:
    container_name: player-pass-backend
    image: jdf90/play-pass-backend
    networks:
      - local_net
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      player-pass-database:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure

  player-pass-frontend:
    container_name: player-pass-frontend
    image: jdf90/play-pass
    networks:
      - local_net
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    links:
      - player-pass-backend

volumes:
  player-pass-db:

networks:
  local_net:
    name: local_net
```

I hope that it is possible to apply the Liquibase changelog as part of the start-up of the Spring Boot application container.

Another solution would be to spin up a separate Liquibase container, responsible for applying the changelog I guess, but I would prefer to keep my local environment and the vm environment as even as possible.

Comment: You managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should properly define the address of your database within container.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  # ... other settings
  player-pass-backend:
    container_name: player-pass-backend
    image: jdf90/play-pass-backend
    # ... other settings
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://player-pass-database:3306/play_pass_db
```

if the above doesn't help, then just try to change your `application.properties` to pick up the env variable as first with default link like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/play_pass_db}
```

with the configuration above it should work for both your docker env and mac env.